# DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-sdk

I have a project `.sln` which i want to build inside Visual studio community 2019, but when i do so , i get this error:-

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB4226 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props"
> was not found. Also, tried to find "DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" in
> the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0" . These search paths are
> defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config". Confirm
> that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
> file exists on disk in one of the search
> paths.    C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\Helper
> Utilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities.sln   C:\c\tree\master\cloud\src\Helper
> Utilities\Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.HelperUtilities\Microsoft.Legal.ProjectCenter.UpdateProjectName\Microsoft.Legal.ProjectCenter.UpdateProjectName.xproj  8

Although i have installed .net core SDK, and i have this version for it:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --version
6.0.301
```

so why i am getting this error?

Comment: Is this related https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/project-doesnot-open-because-of-missing-props/2951 TLDR; Try the .xproj and project.json files, remove the project from the solution and re-add it using the *.csproj file. This was probably due to the rather experimental nature of .NET Core back then.

Comment: @phuzi can you please send me more detailed steps if you can, i am not sure i got what i need to do. thanks

Comment: MS has instructions on [how to upgrade xproj to csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019) there's a section on .NET Core projects (xproj). Seems xproj didn't survive and appears to be unsupported by VS 2019 (v16.3 onwards)

Comment: Sounds like you're going to have to recreate the .csproj files though

Comment: Good news is, it looks like there are only 2 projects still using the old xproj style projects - https://github.com/microsoft/mattercenter/search?q=xproj

Comment: @phuzi removing the .xproj and project.json allowed me to build the project